# How to fill out forms with mechanize python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am writing a script to login to a website and I would like to fill out a form. I can fill out the login form with no problems, but I am unsure how to fill out the actual form once I login. Below is the code I use to get to the form: The form I would like to access is made up of three tabs that navigates between pages.

```
import mechanize
op = mechanize.Browser() # use mecahnize's browser
op.set_handle_robots(False)
url= "http://example.com"
op.open(url)
email = raw_input("Username: ") #ask for username
password = raw_input("Password: ") #ask for password

op.select_form(nr=0) #python labels forms 0,1,2,3 etc. since there is only 1 form, just select 0

op.form["loginForm:user"] = email
op.form["loginForm:pw"] = password
op.submit()

for i in op.forms():
   print i
```

this code prints out: I changed the url and and replace the actual javax.faces thing with x's to protect the original code. When I inspect elements with Chrome on the form, the fields are not shown here. What is going on here?

```
<NavForm POST https://someurl.xhtml application/x-www-form-   urlencoded
<HiddenControl(NavForm=NavForm) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(javax.faces.ViewState=XXXX) (readonly)>>
```

Comment: What happens if you call `op.submit()`?

Comment: @alecxe I forgot to include the submit line. I submit to login, but after that there is no reason to submit as I haven't filled out the form yet.

Comment: So, you can login successfully and want to fill out `NavForm` afterwards?